# How to programmatically access the built-in/core properties of an Excel file using OpenXML sdk 2.0.?

Tags: excel-2010, openxml, openxml-sdk

I would like to access some of the built-in/core properties(like Revision Number, Version Number, etc.) of an Excel 2010 file using OpenXML SDK 2.0. So I wonder if there is any class or any way I could programmatically get and set the core properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a solution for my requirement, I used the below code to do so,

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath,true))
 {
  var props = myWorkbook.PackageProperties;
  string revision = props.Revision;
  props.Revision = "2.5";
  myWorkbook.Close();
 }
```